# Rational Root (algebra)

Tags: polynomials, proof-verification

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $f(x)=a_nx^n+···+a_0$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with integer coefficients. Suppose $r/s∈Q$ is a root of $f$ where $\gcd(r,s) = 1$. Prove that $r$ divides $a_0$ and $s$ divides $a_n$. In particular, if $f$ is a monic polynomial and $f(d) \ne 0$ for all integer divisors of the constant term then $f$ has no roots in $Q[x]$.

I came up with the following proof:

￼￼￼Since we know that $\gcd(r, s) = 1$ then $r$ is in lowest terms. Since $\frac {r}{s}$ is a root then,

$￼￼a_0(\frac {r}{s})^n+a_{n−1}(\frac{r}{s})^{n−1}+...+a_1(\frac{r}{s})+a_0 =0$.

￼￼￼If we multiply by $s^n$ to clear denominators and rearrange the terms to get

$a_0s^n = r[−a_nr^{n−1} − ... − a_1s^{n−1}]$ and $a_nr^n = s[−a_{n−1}r^{n−1} − ... − a_0s^{n−1}]$.

Therefore, $r$ divides $a_0$ and $s$ divides $a_n$.

Does this proof suffice?

Comment: I have edited the tags and removed the last line of your post.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is *correct*, but it would look suspicious upon first glance. In particular, your use of the condition that $\gcd(r,s)=1$ is a bit off the mark. We don't care the $\frac{r}s$ is in lowest terms. We care that we're allowed to jump from
$$r\,\,|\,\,a_0s^n$$
to
$$r\,\,|\,\,a_0$$
eliminating that $s^n$ term. You ought to justify this by using that $r$ and $s$ are coprime - so use that premise at that later point in the proof, rather than confusingly at the start.

Comment: okay thank you. Redone Proof: We see that $\frac{r}{s}$ is a root then, $a_0(\frac{r}{s})^n+a_{n−1}(\frac{r}{s})^{n−1}+...+a_1(\frac{r}{s})+a_0 =0$.
￼￼￼If we multiply by $s^n$ to clear denominators and rearrange the terms to get
$a_0s^n = r[−a_nr^{n−1} − ... − a_1s^{n−1}]$ and $a_nr^n = s[−a_{n−1}r^{n−1} − ... − a_0s^{n−1}]$.
We know that $gcd(r,s) = 1$ then $r$ and $s$ are co-prime.Therefore, $r$ divides $a_0$ and $s$ divides $a_n$.  (Is this better?)

Comment: That looks good to me.